# Array and DESC LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, limit

Here's my problem:

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM s_stats WHERE srv_id='.$sid.' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5';
$result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($row[percent] == null) // don't work
        $procent[] = 1;
    else
        $procent[] = $row[percent];
}
$procent[] = implode('-', $procent);
```

Comment: You should have quotes around "percent". PHP will accept it anyway but you'll get an undefined constant warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `if ($row["percent"] == null || $row["percent"] == "")`

Comment: What exactly doesn't work then? Is the returning true when it shouldn't or false when it should return true?

Comment: I mean, at the line you tagged with // don't work; should the if statement pass or fail and more to the else?

Comment: If the table don't have enough lines (as you can see DESC LIMIT 5) the percent become 1%

Comment: Ahh, that completely changes the whole issue. If a database entry (line) does not exist, it will not be able to enter the while loop for that, thus it never even reaches the if/else statement. I suggest using `mysql_num_rows($q)` to see if there are enough entries and if there aren't, take the appropriate action.

Comment: You're welcome. Please select this answer as accepted if you issue is solved now. : )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `if (! isset($row['percent']))` instead of `if ($row['percent'] == null)`

Comment: Put `echo '*', $row['percent'], '*\n';` before the `if` and see what it prints.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if ($row[percent] === null)
```

When using the non-strict `==` operator, `0 == null` and `'' == null` will evaluate to true as well, which is probably not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM s_stats WHERE srv_id='.$sid.' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5';
$result = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '*', $row['percent'], '*<br/>';
    if (!isset($row["percent"]))
        $procent[] = 1;
    else
        $procent[] = $row[percent];
}
$procent[] = implode('-', $procent);
```

and print:

*12*

*4*

*66*

Comment: Have you chosen to display errors in your dev environment? There seems to be a warning or error about `$row['percent']`. Also try `echo '*', isset($row['percent']), '*<br/>';` to see where the problem arises...

Comment: @Hossein result = > *1*
*1*
*1*

Comment: Oh... Also tell what values did you expect to be printed? Your original data was other than 12 4 66?

Comment: I want 5 numbers > 12 6 66 1 1 (I have only 3 records in the table)